# Mount Grape / Sinatra API in Rails on subdomain

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-grape

My Rails 3 app is using Grape API. I know how to mount that API on a selected route `mount API => '/api'` but I need that api to be accessible on subdomain `api.mydomain.com`.

I searched Grape & Sinatra docs, questions on stack overflow and tried to google it, but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints)

```
YourAppName::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints :subdomain => "api" do
    mount API => '/'
  end
end
```